# What framework does youtube use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, frameworks, youtube, backend

Does anybody know if youtube uses Django, Rails or some other framework?

I googled, but couldn't seem to find any straight forward answer.

Comment: This will likely get closed for...some reason, but here's the last somewhat useful reference point: http://highscalability.com/youtube-architecture - they probably don't go around rewriting the whole thing, but who knows.

Comment: close because its not a programming question. at all.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Presumably this is their stack -

1. [Apache](http://www.apache.org/)
2. [Python](http://python.org/)
3. [Linux Suse](http://www.suse.com/)
4. [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/)
5. [Psyco](http://psyco.sourceforge.net/) - dynamic python-C compiler
6. [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/) - for video instead of apache
7. maybe Java

According to [this website](http://highscalability.com/youtube-architecture). But most of these companies keep it a secret what exactly they use. Even to date its not clear what kind of webservers Google uses...

Comment: Based on their hiring, I'd been assuming 95% Java, 5% Python.